# React timer wont stop at zero

Tags: reactjs

My timer will not stop at zero. It seems like it should be simple.

I am trying to set up my timer as follows:

```
const [ seconds, setSeconds ] = useState(5)

const interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (seconds > 0) {
        setSeconds((seconds) => seconds - 1)
    } else {
        clearInterval(interval)
    }
}, 1000);
```

I'm also rendering the seconds on the front end. Why won't the timer stop at zero? It continues counting into negative numbers.

Comment: State is asynchronous.

Comment: This code is closing over `seconds`, therefore it's always `5`, therefore `5 > 0` is always `true`.